# Align products in Grid type instead of list?

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I've a issue in displaying products in Grid type. Instead of Grid type, all the products are arranged in left side in top-to-bottom format.

I've a `div` called `content` which displays list of products in left side and cart items on right side. The code for to display products:

```
     <div id="content">
        <h2>Spices</h2>               
        <?php    
        $query="SELECT * FROM products";
        $result= mysqli_query($db,$query);
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
         $productname=$row['name'];
         $price=$row['price'];                
        ?>

            <div class="product1">

            <h3><?php echo $productname; ?></h3>
            <img src="images/bp.png" width="170" height="140">
            <p>Starting from <span> Rs. <?php echo $price; ?> </span></p>
            <div id="imgad">
                <a href="#"><img src="images/add-to-cart.png"></a>
            </div>
         <?php   } ?>

        </div>
       </div>
       <?php require_once("sidebar.php");
```

**CSS**

```
#content
{
    width: 700px;
    height: 1200px;
    padding: 5px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #987a7a;

}

#sidebar
{
    width: 250px; 
    height: 500px;
    padding: 5px;
    float: right;
    border: 1px solid #987a7a;
}

 .product1
{
    width: 210px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #c9c5c5; 
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    display: block;  
}
```

The current issue (all are aligned left from top-to-bottom)

[image]

Expected result:

[image]

Comment: try with `display: inline-block;` instead of `float:left;display:block`.

Comment: @JJPA Yes done. But the result is same.

Comment: You have `floats` which are playing a lot in your css. Try to use proper `positioning` and then try :)

Comment: I'm not actually expert in `positioning` & `float`. May be i can solve if you help. But it works well in html when we give date in static. This alignment issue arises while only when i fetch data from database.

Comment: i think you should also check for changing css during fetch in developer mode of browser

Comment: @himanshu Oh. Where do you think that i've to change css? I mean in which `div`?

Comment: i m not saying to change css i am talking to check with F12 on browser

Comment: Yes, i did. The first item takes the width that i've mentioned in css. i.e 210px. After that, the next items is going down and displaying it.

Comment: did you remove display: block;

Comment: Yes i did.
I just can't figure out where the problem exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 .product1
{
    width: 210px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #c9c5c5; 
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;  
}
```

display:inline-block show content in line

update:

after watch the demo page[DEMO](http://testdomain56.host56.com/) i can say that the problem is your divs are not closing properly

Comment: yeah i just noticed that and was removing

Comment: I've tried this code. But same result. It works well in html when we give date in static. But while fetching data from database..this alignment problem arises.

Comment: The problem is not closing the div properly. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: inline-block`, like this:

```css
.product1
{
    width: 210px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #c9c5c5; 
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

Like this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mj33kr95/).